# OpenVPN and advertising FQDN

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

Is there a config available for openVPN to advertise FQDN over the VPN connection.

At my house, I don't have my own DNS server. Just know that after a few minutes on my lan,

```
arp -a
```

gives me a route to all of the machines in my house with their FQDN.

So, I can do something like,

```
ssh root@server.local # Server = 192.168.1.12
```

However, when connected via openVPN, I can only reach it by doing

```
ssh root@192.168.1.12
```

Is there a way to advertise (if that the right word) the fqdns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to push your internal DNS servers to your OpenVPN clients.  https://serverfault.com/questions/318563/how-to-push-my-own-dns-server-to-openvpn

Of course, you don't say that you're running a DNS server for local resolution, you may just be relying on Bonjour mdns for that.  If that's the case, you need to setup bridged mode and use clients that support Bonjour.  http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-07/msg00106.html